# Excluding a a folder from test runs with TestNG and Gradle

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to exclude a 'quarantine' folder that I set up for Selenium tests that need to be updated and I do not wish to have run. I know that one solution is to set up and assign test groups for the tests in these classes but given the sheer size and volume of tests that will be in here, I'd rather do it using an Ant-style filter.

Here is a snippet of my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.35.0"
    compile "org.testng:testng:5.14.10"
    testCompile('org.uncommons:reportng:1.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.testng'
    }
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
    compile "com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:1.8.1"
}

//initialize thread count variable for parallel testing and default to 1
def threadCount = System.getProperty("MAXTHREADS", "1")

tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 1
    forkEvery = 1000
    ignoreFailures = false

    // Pass all system properties to the tests
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()

    // Makes the standard streams (err and out) visible at console when running tests
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    exclude '**/tasks/'
    exclude '**/disabled/'

    classpath += configurations.testCompile
}

task firefox(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        exceptionFormat "full" // default is "short"
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome'
        useDefaultListeners = false
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/firefox")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/firefox")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'firefox')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}

task chrome(type: Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Integer.valueOf(threadCount) //default is 1 if not specified
    testLogging.events "started"
    useTestNG() {
        useDefaultListeners = false;
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
        listeners << 'com.xmatters.testng.Listener'
    }

    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/chrome")
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/chrome")

    systemProperties.BROWSER = System.getProperty('BROWSER', 'chrome')

    exclude '**/selenium/'
    exclude '**/setupscripts/'
}
```

On line 34 you can see `exclude '**/disabled/'` that I added. This folder is a couple levels up from the root folder. The preceding like with `exclude '**/tasks/'` was already in the build file and seems to work fine with a similar directory structure.

When I run the build, tests in the /disabled/ folder are still getting run. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm assuming that with that syntax, a directory named 'exclude' a couple levels up would be ignored by `scanForTestClasses` which is true by default. Any idea what is up here?

One other thing I've noticed in Gradle test report is that the package name listed in the report is `default-package`for the excluded tests that are not 'excluding' whereas the other tests that are meant to be run are listing the correct package names. The package names in the Java files match their folder structure correctly so I'm not sure why this is being reported this way. I've checked for duplicates, typos, etc, and am not getting anywhere.

If anyone could shed some light on this that would be great as having these incomplete / broken test classes running is causing failures that should be ignored until these tests are updated.

These test are being run using the Gradle wrapper generated bash script on our test CI (Jenkins) box running on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the exclude pattern is applied to the relative path of the files (i.e. relative to your root folder), which explains why it works for folders under your root folder.

Using an excludeSpec (see [Gradle Test task DSL](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test%3aexclude%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)) should work fine:

```
exclude { it.file.canonicalPath.contains('/disabled/')}
```

Of course, pay attention to / vs \ according to your OS.